# Parse.com: Determine how much file space my app uses

Tags: parse-platform

Parse.com currently has a 20GB file storage limit on its free account, and I can't seem to find out where to determine how much space my files are using (have checked here, docs, and forums).

Does anyone know how to check this stat in Parse Apps?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the analytics part of the web interface?

Answer (score 4):

You can view File Storage stats in dashboard: Your App -> Analytics -> Performance -> Billing data as of today (File Storage / Database Storage / Data Transfer)

If usage doesn't show up the files might not be linked to Parse Objects. In which case refer to: https://parse.com/questions/file-storage-usage

Hope this helps.